# Matchit plugin is not working when I put it in my .vimrc. However it works when I run the same command manually inside Vim

Tags: plugin-matchit

I have the following lines in my .vimrc.

```
colorscheme elflord

set incsearch

set guifont=Monospace\ 13 
" <Ctrl-l> redraws the screen and removes any search highlighting.
nnoremap <silent> <C-l> :nohl<CR><C-l>

runtime macros/matchit.vim
runtime ftplugin/system_verilog.vim
syntax on
filetype on 
filetype indent on 
filetype plugin on
set nocompatible
set lines=40 columns=150
set nu
```

But it is not able to match the pairs inside vim automatically. However if I do the following command inside the vim, it is able to detect the pairs with `%`.

```
runtime ftplugin/system_verilog.vim
```

Can you please help me to fix it to be done automatically whenever I open gvim?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from your question, you're attempting to use the `matchit` plugin in a Systemverilog file and it's not working how you'd expect.

If you edit your question to be more specific about exactly what you're doing and what you're expecting to happen I can be more specific in my advice. Still, the following part of your `vimrc` stands out:

The `runtime` lines in your `vimrc` aren't the recommended way of enabling plugins (and don't do what I'm guessing you think they do).

### How to enable matchit

If you're running Vim 8, then you enable matchit by adding the following line to your `vimrc`:

```
packadd! matchit
```

If you're still on Vim 7, then instead of editing your `vimrc`, you install matchit by running the following commands from an existing Vim instance:

```
:!mkdir ~/.vim
:!mkdir ~/.vim/plugin
:!cp $VIMRUNTIME/macros/matchit.vim ~/.vim/plugin
```

See [`:help matchit`](https://www.vimhelp.org/usr_05.txt.html#matchit-install) for more details.

### Systemverilog filetype

In order to use Vim's standard configuration for Systemverilog you just need to enable Vim's syntax and/or filetype plugins, and then ensure that the `'filetype'` is set to `systemverilog` when editing a Systemverilog file.

You can do this manually by running the command `:set ft=systemverilog` from a Systemverilog file, but since you've turned on filetype detection, Vim will automatically set the `'filetype'` to `systemverilog` and load its filetype/syntax/indent files when you open any file with an `.sv` or `.svh` extension.

See [`:help filetype`](https://www.vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#filetype) for more details, and [`:help new-filetype`](https://www.vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#new-filetype) if you need Vim to detect Systemverilog files that *don't* have an `.sv` or `.svh` extension.